# Why is this ListView not changing with changes to the bound property?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

Basic question from a novice.  I've been stuck on this and have read through a lot of material and several similar questions on SO; hopefully not a completely duplicate question.  I simplified the code as much as I know how to.

I'm trying to make the ListView show a filtered ObservableCollection) property (as the ItemsSource?), based on the selection in the ComboBox. 
 Specifically, which "meetings" have this "coordinator" related to it.

I'm not seeing any data errors in the output while it's running and debugging shows the properties updating correctly, but the ListView stays blank.  I'm trying to avoid any code-behind on the View, there is none currently.

Thanks!

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Meeting> meetings;
    public ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings
    {
        get
        {
            return meetings;
        }
        set
        {
            meetings = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListProperty");
            OnPropertyChanged("Meetings");
        }
    }

    private string coordinatorSelected;
    public string CoordinatorSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return coordinatorSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            coordinatorSelected = value;
            Meetings = fakeDB.Where(v => v.CoordinatorName == CoordinatorSelected) as ObservableCollection<Meeting>;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> comboProperty = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Joe", "Helen", "Sven" };
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return comboProperty;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Meeting> fakeDB = new ObservableCollection<Meeting>() { new Meeting("Joe", "Atlas"), new Meeting("Sven", "Contoso"), new Meeting("Helen", "Acme") };
    public ObservableCollection<Meeting> ListProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return Meetings;
        }
    }

    public class Meeting
    {
        public string CoordinatorName { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public Meeting(string coordinatorName, string clientName)
        {
            CoordinatorName = coordinatorName;
            ClientName = clientName;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="VM"></local:ViewModel>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}">
    <ComboBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboProperty}" SelectedItem="{Binding CoordinatorSelected}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding ListProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="ClientName"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Update:

[image]

This seems to show that the lambda is returning a Meeting object but the assignment to Meetings is failing.  Is this an error in casting maybe?

Thanks again.

Comment: The option isn't required here, using only the source works - `ItemsSource="{Binding ListProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a OneWay Binding. It controls how a TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding updates its source property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found two solutions to the same problem.  The error pointed out @Clemens was also part of the solution.  The Meetings property problem is solved if I change ListProperty and Meetings to IEnumerable.  Alternatively this approach without changing the type, which I believe invokes the collection's constructor with the filtered sequence as an argument.

```
set
{
    coordinatorSelected = value;
    var filteredList = fakeDB.Where(v => v.CoordinatorName == coordinatorSelected);
    Meetings = new ObservableCollection<Meeting>(filteredList);
    OnPropertyChanged("ListProperty");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You always have to change a property's backing field before you fire a PropertyChanged event. Otherwise a consumer of the event would still get the old value when it reads the property.

Change the Meetings property setter like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings
{
    get
    {
        return meetings;
    }
    set
    {
        meetings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListProperty");
        OnPropertyChanged("Meetings");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Nice catch, I've corrected that error.  I think there is a problem with the assignment to Meetings in the setter - I will update the question to fix the code and include a screenshot of the debugger.  I think it might be a casting issue but it looks right to me.